# Android theme changes do not change reliably

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am trying to learn how to edit custom app themes in Android.

But for some reason changes in my styles.xml (manually and with theme editor) are being reflected on my device in an unreliable sporadic way. The behavior is perplexing.

Like I did 50 build , cleans, rebuild, etc last night trying to get option menu items text to change color and it wouldn't. Then today it just changed...and I dont know why.

I try to change the main background color, and it wouldn't change. Then all of a sudden after a build the optionmenu background color changed to the color I set main background color to.

I have not found anything reliable or reproducible in this problem.

Theme changes just are not working for me and when they do it is sporadically.

I have disabled instant run, and uninstalled app, as well as cleaned , rebuild, and made project. None of those actions have any effect on whether theme changes will take hold.

My v11, v14, and v21 styles.xml are empty, and I only modify the main styles.xml.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!--
    Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
    res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
    backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/text_color_inverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MenuItemTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

```
androidmanifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.me.myapp"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".LocalApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ActMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActExport"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_export"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
        </activity>
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".ActSaveFile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_act_save_file">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActLoadFile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_act_load_file">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style AppBasteTheme which extends from android:Theme.Material is supported only above 21 sdk level your min sdk level is 15 which is small.Instead of this use this style which works fine.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!--
Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
backward-compatibility can go here.
-->
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:colorForeground">@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/text_color_inverse</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_primary</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MenuItemTextAppearance</item>
<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the behavior I am seeing though.

Comment: Error:(119) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like this you missed additional styles.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```